# What the best payment form to be paid for clients from foreign countries?

Tags: payments

I would to know which the *best payment* form to be paid for clients from *foreign countries*?

For example, is *Paypal* a good option for it? Any useful tips or other options are all welcome.

Comment: Get 100% payment up front. Trying to collect on diligent accounts across international borders is a nightmare.

Comment: Welcome to Freelancing.SE! Can you describe what you would qualify as "best"? Please [edit] the question to include some measurable details we can authoritatively answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, the best one is **transferwise.com** for its fast service, low fees and great customer support. Else, to secure your contracts you have to set it in trustful platform such as **upwork** or **freelancer.com** or **hellosign.com**

Comment: So, out of freelancer platforms as the ones you cited above not even thinking, right?

Comment: never start working or accept a freelancing job outside a protected environment. Else your client will have the possibility to not pay you and you could do nothing about that rather than prepare some thousands to hire a lawyer which doesn't sound a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Transferwise is a great option simply because of its low costs and wide availability, however, they don't accept credit cards. Paypal or Stripe are generally quite good also, but if you run into a chargeback, you can depend upon neither to do anything to support you. Lastly, bitcoin exchanges are a great method if you want to accept payments from countries where the other two are not available.